# How could Play help me to prevent parameter tampering attack?

Tags: playframework-2.0

> if there is not a direct 1:1 mapping between the form and the model,
>   then sensitive fields must be explicitly ignored to prevent a
>   parameter tampering attack.

I have seen this sentence in Play documentation at https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms#Defining-constraints-on-the-form

what they are really saying? and what does it mean? 
or how can play help me to do that

Answer (score 3):

It's saying if I have a model:

```
case class User(name: String, email: String, isAdmin: Boolean)
```

And I reuse that model for creating an edit form that only exposed the `name` and `email` parameters as fields in the html, I have to be careful, because when it gets submitted, an attacker could add an additional parameter, `isAdmin=true`, which would end up making themselves an admin.  In contrast, if I have a specific form class:

```
case class UserForm(name: String, email: String)

case class User(name: String, email: String, isAdmin: Boolean) {
  def updateFromForm(userForm: UserForm): User =
    user.copy(name = userForm.name, email = userForm.email)
}
```

Then there's no chance of that happening, since there's no field to bind `isAdmin` to.

In practice, this point is not that relevant to the Play Scala form API, since it is very explicit about declaring all the bindings anyway.  In contrast, reflection based APIs such as the Play Java form API definitely have this problem.

Comment: As usually great point, anyway it's also worth to mention that in Java API it's possible, what's more highly recommended (because of exactly this problem) to bind forms via custom form classes. Old good saying "_Never trust the user_" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Given that the idiomatic Play way to handle entities that are ID specific (e.g. entities that have an database ID field on them that you do not want to expose to the user) is to use a hidden field I been wondering this exact thing myself.

Play has the CSRFCheck Composite Action that can be welded into a Controller (with CSRFAddToken before you send the form) however this does nothing to prevent a hidden field with an ID from being updated.

Served ID=1 (hidden) Name="Fred" Password="NoneOfYourBusiness"

Returned ID=2 (hidden) Name="Freddie" Password="NowIOwnYouTwo"

I'm kinda shocked that url and/or parameter tampering isn't handled by this same mechanism or by Play directly.

You could grab the CSRFToken and cache it (or store it in the DB) along with the ID it is supposed to protect but if you are going to go to that trouble then you just might as well exclude the ID altogether as a hidden field and cache/store it at the server side and reference it (look it back up on the inbound request) with the sessionID or the CSRFToken itself.

OR

Go one step further and generate yet another encrypted string that contains the required info along with an expiry date which basically mirrors the URL in question (which you should be able to get from the reverse routing) and is parsed on the way back in to check if each and every param is allowed / is valid / is not tampered with. Seems like a lot of work but it may be the minimum required to ensure "good behaviour" :)

Doing all of this starts to eat away at the memory advantage that a stateless framework offers (IMHO) -- which points towards sending the data encrypted so as not to eat up your server's memory but of course now you pay with CPU and bandwidth.

Remember that this only needs to be done on the POSTs as all GETs should not change state server side.  If nothing changes all you need worry about is if the eyeballs are authorized not if they are behaving to not.